# Is there a way to have a simple paste macro, paste onto a cell by matching dates?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]
[image]

I've got a excel workbook that has a macro written. It takes information from one sheet and pastes it to another. However each month the data range changes. Currently tracking a 12 month roll. So current month is Feb we use data from Feb 2014 - Jan 2015.

That being said there is the current date on both sheets. Is there a way to add to my pre-existing macro to paste it into the correct cells that line up with the correct date range. Or to take the data 12 lines and paste it into the other sheet on the current month range?

```
Sub Paste_to_UnitProfile()
'
' Paste_to_UnitProfile Macro
'

'
    Range("D2:D13").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlFirst
    Sheets("Unit Profile").Select
    Range("G151").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I'm adding the INDEX/MATCH that I tried to use on this but I'm new to this and I'm sure there's something small that I'm goofing up on:

```
=INDEX(PS250-'1EngineHours'!D2:D13,MATCH(E151,UnitProfile!G151:G170,0))
```

Comment: Possibly even as simple as just adding to paste it down one row every time it's clicked on ? Maybe that will be an easier solution.

Comment: hi, if you can post some sample data it would be much more easier to help.

Comment: Pics have been added !

Comment: Wouldn't a formula with `INDEX(MATCH())`, `VLOOKUP` or even `SUMIFS`  be more appropriate than a macro?

Comment: It might be but I haven't the first clue on how to do a VLOOKUP. I'm relatively new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'ld add this to the start to get the first last row to read from and the first row to write to.

```
i = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4).Value)
    i = i + 1
Loop
StartRead = i - 12
EndRead = i - 1

i = 9
Do Until Sheets("Unit profile").Cells(i, 4).Value = Sheets("Unit profile").Cells(5, 2).Value
        i = i + 1
Loop
StartWrite =  i
```

Then just change the paste code to:

```
Range(Cells(StartRead, 4), Cells(EndRead, 4)).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlFirst
Sheets("Unit Profile").Select
Cells(StartWrite, 5).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I'ld also add to the start:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

And then to the end:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Just to make it a bit neater

Comment: I seem to be getting a run-time error on the 'Do Until Sheets ............." portion

Comment: Does it give you any more information? Problem might be that the cells are of different formats, i.e. Feb-14 is date format of 2015-02-14 while the other 'Feb-14' is  in string format.

Comment: If that's the case the easiest way is of course to change the format of either of the cells.

Comment: I tried this and keep getting errors:                                                                          =INDEX(PS250-'1EngineHours'!D2:D13,MATCH(E151,UnitProfile!G151:G170,0))

Comment: Dont know if it's a typo just now but in your text you say the sheet name is "Unit Profile" but in this MATCH segment it's "UnitProfile".